# Ansible Wants Vault Password for Unnecessary File

Tags: ansible

In my hosts file, I have `GroupA` and `GroupB`. Configuration for GroupB includes some sensitive data, and therefore I created `group_vars/GroupB.yml` and encrypted it with Ansible Vault.

I have a playbook with `hosts: GroupA`. When I run the playbook, Ansible fails because I didn't provide the password for `group_vars/GroupB.yml`. But `GroupB` was never invoked anywhere, so why would it try  to decrypt that file? What might I be overlooking or misunderstanding - or is this in fact the intended behavior?

Comment: Ansible isn't very smart about this.

If you specify `--ask-vault-pass` then it will _always_ ask for the vault password, even if it's not needed.

And if you _don't_ specify it, then it will die ungracefully if you have _any_ encrypted files, even if they aren't needed.

Comment: That is exactly it - I'm getting the "die ungracefully" response. I can understand the scenario where I want to run a certain role on GroupB, and that role doesn't need the encrypted data. Ansible can't know that there's no relevant variable in there, unless it decrypts and reads the file. But in my case I'm not doing anything with GroupB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible reads the entire inventory and group vars before execution, so even if no hosts are in GroupB, the vars still need to be decrypted.

If you don't like typing the vault pass you can pass a file path with it in.